# UWP - How to ignore system text scaling settings

Tags: responsive-design, uwp, accessibility

I have a "problem" with the text scaling setting (All settings -> Ease of Access -> More options). It increases the text size and creak my design. For example, texts of my menu are cut.
So, I have two questions:

- In applications developed by Microsoft, this particularity is "ignored" and text sizes is always the same (eg: News, Sports, Weather, ...) but how to do it?
- If Microsoft uses very bad practices in the previous point, what is the best way to manage this settings.

Thanks

Comment: If you want your app to adhere to the Ease of Access settings, never use Fixed Width/Height, That will solve 90% of your issues. If you have a xaml that is giving you an error. Update your question with that xaml and we can point out exactly where view is implemented the way it should not be implemented..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want the text automatically scales according to the system text size setting, you can set [**IsTextScaleFactorEnabled**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.istextscalefactorenabled) property to **`false`**. This property indicates whether automatic text enlargement is enabled to reflect the system text size setting and by default, its value is `true`. For example, in `TextBlock`, use it like following:

```xml
<TextBlock FontSize="20" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False">Test</TextBlock>
```

Other than `TextBlock`, there is a lot of other types have an `IsTextScaleFactorEnabled` property. And we can also use the **[TextScaleFactorChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn633867)** event and the **[TextScaleFactor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn633866)** property to find out about changes to the Text size setting on the phone.

For more info, please see [**Text scale factor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/accessibility/accessible-text-requirements#text-scale-factor) in [Accessible text requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/accessibility/accessible-text-requirements).